# Breaking out of Docker container to root on host filesystem

Tags: docker

I was following the below youtube video linked in the article which allows a docker container to get root access on the host.

There are a few steps which are unclear, can someone please explain how they work further?

https://www.lvh.io/posts/dont-expose-the-docker-socket-not-even-to-a-container.html

```
    Step 1> Bind mount /var/run/docker.sock from host to container
    Step 2> Install docker in container   <<< at this stage I see that docker ps 
    -a shows all the containers which are present on the host.
    **QUESTION:** How can the container see the containers present on the host? Is it because dockerd on the new container is using /var/run/docker.sock on the host? netstat/ss in the new container doesn't show anything..  

    Step 3> Run another container from the 1st container. Pass the following parameters to it:
        docker run -dit -v /:/host ubuntu

Intention of this is to mount / from host filesystem to /host in the 2nd container being created
         **QUESTION:** How does the 1st container have access to / (being filesystem of the host?)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Docker runs as a `service` on the host machine. This `service` communicates with clients via a socket which, by default, is the unix socket: `unix:/var/run/docker.sock`.

When you share this socket with any container, that container will get full access to the docker daemon. From there, the container could start other containers, delete containers/volumes/etc or even map volumes at will from the host to a new container, for example, as is described in your question with `-v /:/host`. Doing that will give the container root access to the host file system in `/host/`.

In short: you should be careful sharing this precious socket with any container you don't trust. In some cases the shared socket makes sense (for example `portainer`: a container that serves as a management GUI to docker).

Comment: Two corollaries: don’t design your application to make Docker API calls in response to network calls (if you don’t get this perfect you risk rooting the host); never ever use the Docker daemon `-H` option to open remote network access to the Docker daemon (anyone who can reach the port can do what this answer describes).

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks :) you'd be surprised/frightened by how many popped up the last time I ran a `masscan` across my hosting provider on port 2376. I'm convinced that there's someone out there suggesting exactly this on some vlog for docker juniors.